# Movable Type: remove part of URL using regex replace

Tags: regex, movabletype

I want to remove part uf url using regex_replace I tried below but its not working right. I am trying to remove "index1.php"

Code input:

```
http://www.myblog.com/blog/content/fruit/index1.php
```

my code

```
<mt:getvar name="permalink" regex_replace="/index1\.(php)$/","">
```

Code output:

```
http://www.myblog.com/blog/content/fruit/index1.php
```

But it should be

```
http://www.myblog.com/blog/content/fruit/
```

Comment: What's the output of your code? Wh don't you use this `regex_replace="/index1\.php$/",""`

Comment: @AvinashRaj the output should be "http://www.myblog.com/blog/content/fruit/" I also edited the page to make more sense.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I made a mistake output is http://www.myblog.com/blog/content/fruit/index1.php

Comment: you said "I am trying to remove "index1.php""

Comment: yes I want to remove index1.php part

Comment: try `<mt:getvar name="permalink" regex_replace="index1\.php$/","">`

Comment: I tried that and didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try the following pattern:

```
<mt:getvar name="permalink" regex_replace="/\/[^\/]+$\/","">
```

or, try using a capture group:

```
<mt:getvar name="permalink" regex_replace="/(.*\/)index1[.]php$\/","$1">
```

Answer (score 0):

For the example you posted you don't need to use `regex_replace`, you can just use [`replace`](https://movabletype.org/documentation/appendices/modifiers/replace.html):

```
<mt:GetVar name="permalink" replace="index1.php","">
```

It's not clear if you might be planning to use `regex_replace` to actually do a regular expression match (perhaps the number varies or something), but if not, replace is easier and faster.